# Scraping information from hoverbox

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As background, I am scraping a webpage in Python and using BeautifulSoup.

Some of the information that I need to access is a little box about user profiles that pops up when the mouse hovers over the user's profile picture. The problem, is that this information is not available in the html, instead, I get the following:

""div class="username mo"
 span class="expand_inline scrname mbrName_1586A02614A388AEE215B4A3139A2C18" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews', 'show_reviewer_info_window', 'user_name_name_click')">Sapphire-Ed
""
(I have deleted some of the >s so that the html will show up in the question, sorry!)

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thank you for the help!!

Here is the webpage if that is helpful:
view-source:http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g143010-d108269-Reviews-Cadillac_Mountain-Acadia_National_Park_Mount_Desert_Island_Maine.html
The information I am trying to access is the review distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the complete working code that outputs a dictionary where the keys are usernames and the values are review distributions. To understand how the code works, here are the key things to take into an account:

- the information in the overlay appearing on the mouse over is loaded dynamically with a HTTP GET request with a number of user-specific parameters - the most important are `uid` and `src`
- the `uid` and `src` values can be extracted with a regular expression from the `id` attribute for every user profile element
- the response to this GET request is HTML which you need to parse with `BeautifulSoup` also
- you should maintain the web-scraping session with [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)

The code:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {}

# this pattern would help us to extract uid and src needed to make a GET request
pattern = re.compile(r"UID_(\w+)-SRC_(\w+)")

# making a web-scraping session
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = requests.get("http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g143010-d108269-Reviews-Cadillac_Mountain-Acadia_National_Park_Mount_Desert_Island_Maine.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

    # iterating over usernames on the page
    for member in soup.select("div.member_info div.memberOverlayLink"):
        # extracting uid and src from the `id` attribute
        match = pattern.search(member['id'])
        if match:
            username = member.find("div", class_="username").text.strip()
            uid, src = match.groups()

            # making a GET request for the overlay information
            response = session.get("http://www.tripadvisor.com/MemberOverlay", params={
                "uid": uid,
                "src": src,
                "c": "",
                "fus": "false",
                "partner": "false",
                "LsoId": ""
            })

            # getting the grades dictionary
            soup_overlay = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
            data[username] = {grade_type: soup_overlay.find("span", text=grade_type).find_next_sibling("span", class_="numbersText").text.strip(" ()")
                              for grade_type in ["Excellent", "Very good", "Average", "Poor", "Terrible"]}


pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'Anna T': {'Average': '2',
            'Excellent': '0',
            'Poor': '0',
            'Terrible': '0',
            'Very good': '2'},
 'Arlyss T': {'Average': '0',
              'Excellent': '6',
              'Poor': '0',
              'Terrible': '0',
              'Very good': '1'},
 'Bf B': {'Average': '1',
          'Excellent': '22',
          'Poor': '0',
          'Terrible': '0',
          'Very good': '17'},
 'Charmingnl': {'Average': '15',
                'Excellent': '109',
                'Poor': '4',
                'Terrible': '4',
                'Very good': '45'},
 'Jackie M': {'Average': '2',
              'Excellent': '10',
              'Poor': '0',
              'Terrible': '0',
              'Very good': '4'},
 'Jonathan K': {'Average': '69',
                'Excellent': '90',
                'Poor': '6',
                'Terrible': '0',
                'Very good': '154'},
 'Sapphire-Ed': {'Average': '8',
                 'Excellent': '47',
                 'Poor': '2',
                 'Terrible': '0',
                 'Very good': '49'},
 'TundraJayco': {'Average': '14',
                 'Excellent': '59',
                 'Poor': '0',
                 'Terrible': '1',
                 'Very good': '49'},
 'Versrii': {'Average': '2',
             'Excellent': '8',
             'Poor': '0',
             'Terrible': '0',
             'Very good': '10'},
 'tripavisor83': {'Average': '12',
                  'Excellent': '9',
                  'Poor': '1',
                  'Terrible': '0',
                  'Very good': '20'}}
```

Comment: you are a saint! ;-) Good luck to all.